# Getting Room database reference inside appmodule

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I have an application where i need to prepopulate my database when it is created , i'm using dagger hilt to inject and provide dependencies ( room daos ) , when i try to insert data , it asks for movie database but don't know how to get its reference inside appmodule, thank you for any help in advance.

- This is my database :

```
  // this is my database 
 
@Database(entities = [DataModel::class,MovieResultItem::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class MoviesDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
 
    abstract fun popularDao() : PopularMoviesDao
 
}
```

- Providing dao as dependency

```
  @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providePopularMoviesDao(moviesDatabase: MoviesDatabase) : PopularMoviesDao {
        return moviesDatabase.popularDao()
    }
```

- Providing database instance

```
  @Singleton
   @Provides
   fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): MoviesDatabase {
       return Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
               MoviesDatabase::class.java, "movie.db")
               .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback(){
                   override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                       super.onCreate(db)

                       // here it asks for database instance , not sure how to get it 
                       providePopularMoviesDao().insertPopularMovies(getMovieResultItem())
                      
                   }
               })
               .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
               .build()
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Database(entities = [DataModel::class,MovieResultItem::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class MoviesDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun popularDao(): PopularMoviesDao

    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: MoviesDatabase? = null

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): MoviesDatabase {
        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            val databaseInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                MoviesDatabase::class.java, "movie.db"
            )
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .addCallback(InsertDatabaseCallback())
                .build()

            INSTANCE = databaseInstance
            return instance



            private class InsertDatabaseCallback() :RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                    super.onOpen(db)
                    INSTANCE?.let {
                        it.providePopularMoviesDao().insertPopularMovies(getMovieResultItem())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Would you please use the above code in your class `MoviesDatabase`.

1. Here I have added an `INSTANCE` variable for database and it is marked as `Volatile`.
2. Volatile means, it will not be stored in the local cache. There are lot of articles you can explore for more information on Volatile.
3. I have modified the `provideDatabase` function, so that the database instance is stored in variable `INSTANCE`
4. Then you can use this `INSTANCE` wherever required.
5. Also, I have separated the callback into class `InsertDatabaseCallback` for simpilicity and readability. Here you can use the database INSTANCE to perform your operation `providePopularMoviesDao().insertPopularMovies(getMovieResultItem())`

**NOTE**: The code may show syntax error or curly braces error, depending on your setup and imports. Do not worry there, please make slight changes OR add curly brackets (if required) and it should work fine.

Comment: thank you for the reply , but keep in mind , i don't have any code in my database cause i m already creating database instance with dagger-hilt , that's why i face this mainly as i m nto getting instance of it inside my appmodule